# drilling from powerbi to ssrs

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, powerbi, drillthrough

I currently have a suite of about 25 SSRS reports.  Some are very high level and from there you can drill into more detailed reports. Some of the high level reports are basically simulated pivot views of the data in a matrix with drillthroughs on each cell.  A pain to set up, but it turned out pretty cool except that you can't manipulate it like a pivot table, you need to make a new SSRS report for each scenario that you might want to see.

I was wondering if it is possible to harness the power of PowerBI, maybe a powerpivot and drill from there into SSRS reports, passing the parameters that figure into the cell that you are clicking on?

I'm new to PowerBI and I started to set one up today but can't find any information about drilling into SSRS reports.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

We're adding hyperlink support in current/soon to be available builds. You'll use it in two ways. First, you can specify a custom drill url on a dashboard tile. Just edit the tile properties and the option will be in the pane that opens.  So you could point those urls to your SSRS reports.  Second, in tables in your reports, you'll be able to have hyperlinks. So you could create a calculated column that returns parameterized urls that drill to your SSRS reports.